# Begginer question about lifelink and Evra

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Evra, Halcyon Witness](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEvra%2c%20Halcyon%20Witness%5d) on my deck, she has lifelink and I know that I gain hp from the amount of damage she deals.

Generalizing lifelink I have 3 simple yes or no questions:

- If I attack with her and the opponent blocks me does she give me hp for the amount of damage she deals to that creature?
- If the opponent attacks and I block with her, is the damage she deals returned to me as hp even if she is blocking?
- Do creatures with lifelink only transform damage dealt into hp gain when they only attack the opponent?

And 1 about Evra?

- If I activate the ability to exchange my hp for her power and i get countered with an instant giving -4/0, like "Befuddle" does, does the exchange still happen and I instantly die?

Comment: Fun fact - if you `fight` with Evra, like with [Ancient Animus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443042) you gain life!

Comment: "Deals damage" means many things depending what is dealing the damage and what is being damaged. Most commonly, it adds marked damage, it reduces life totals, or it causes loss of loyalty counters. It can also add -1/-1 or poison counters. Independently, it can also increase life totals. This is what lifelike does; it redefines "deals damage" so that it causes life gain in addition to its normal effects.

Answer (score 1):

Lifelink on a creature causes you to gain life whenever that creature deals damage in any way. In combat, unblocked creatures deal damage to the defending player, and blocking creatures and blocked creatures deal damage to each other. So if Evra is in any of those situations then it will deal damage and you will gain that much life. One common exception is if Evra blocks or becomes blocked, then the other creature is removed from combat before the damage is dealt. Then Evra will have nothing to deal damage to, so it won't deal any damage and you won't gain any life.

Regarding Evra's other ability, you are correct that if Evra's power somehow becomes 0 before the ability resolves, the ability will make your life total 0 and you will lose.

Comment: ty, now i understand how it works :)

Comment: another question, can i excede the 20 hp, imagin i have 20 hp and i atack with evra and lifelink 4 from her power, does that make me have 24 hp ?? asking this because in hearthstone the same ability doesent make me excede my hp

Comment: Not only can you do it, but some cards only fully work when you do, like [Path of Bravery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=438592)

Answer (score 1):

A creature with lifelink gains you life whenever it deals damage (usually in combat, but sometimes when a card says it fights another creature). Combat damage happens during combat whether the lifelink creature is attacking or bloking (assuming first strike or double strike is not on any of the involved creatures).

Also, in Magic the Gathering it's called Life Total not hp.

Therefore:

> If i atack with her and opp block me does she give me hp for the ammount of damage she deals to that creature?

Yes. She deals all of her damage and you gain 4 life.

> Opp atacks and i block with her, The damage she deals is returned to me as hp even if she is blocking?

Yes. She deals all of her damage and you gain 4 life.

> Creatures with lifelink only transform damage dealt into hp gain when they only atack the opp(opponent)

No. You gain life whenever damage is dealt regardless of combat (attacking or blocking) or fighting.

Comment: another question, can i excede the 20 hp, imagin i have 20 hp and i atack with evra and lifelink 4 from her power, does that make me have 24 hp ?? asking this because in hearthstone the same ability doesent make me excede my hp

Comment: There is no minimum or maximum level on your life total unless a card in play specifically mentions otherwise. Example, you can get to 1,000,000 life (I've seen it) or -24 (in which case you instantly lose).

Comment: @Rogue-OP All life totals less that 0 are considered to be 0. If your life total reaches -24, then next time states are checked, your life total will be set to 0. And there are cards that let you not lose with 0 life total.

Comment: @Acccumulation in response to getting to -24, you can cast a spell to gain you 25 life (as an example) which would put you at 1 and keep you alive. Counting down to negatives is important for this reason.